# Sql Query to XML document inside Drupal

Tags: sql, xml, drupal

I need to be able to dump my user table inside Drupal to an XML document that I can hit from a path in a browser.

e.g. mysite.com/users.php

Looking for an easy way to do this, an existing module would be ideal.  Not sure if QueryPath does this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) you can first build a [view](http://drupal.org/project/views) of all your users, and then create a 'feed' display. In the feed settings, you'll be able to select XML as one of the formats. You can then set the path to anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

QueryPath can do this.

There is a database extension that comes with QueryPath's Drupal module that basically lets you take any SQL statement and inject the results into an XML document. The basic idea is explained here:

http://technosophos.com/content/using-querypath-interact-sql-database-part-1

The Drupal module has Drupal-specific DB bindings though. (So stuff like {table} is correctly translated.)

I've also used the Views Datasource module to do this, but it's buggy. The last two times I did it, I had to edit the source code for the module first.